# не работает функция, в чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

по нажатию на `.delete-input` должен удаляться элемент с `#add"+rel`

Вот пример

```js
$('.delete-input').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#add" + rel).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("#add" + rel).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="add2" class="addimages str">
  <a class="delete-input" rel="2">Удалить</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Зачем меняете код в вопросе с неработающего на работающий? В чем тогда вопрос?

Comment: @Igor, проверял работает ли вариант или нет, сейчас обратно изменю, дело в том что у себя я попробовал убрать 'a' и все равно не работает, а тут все работает...

Comment: Заработало у Вас?

Comment: @Igor, нет, дело в том что эту строки изначально не существует, по нажатию добавит она появляется, а по нажатию на удалить исчезать, но дело в том что если при загрузки страницы строка будет существовать, то она удалить, а добавленные строки не удаляются. Есть на первой сайте рабочий вариант, так все без ошибок, а вот решил такое же реализовать на другом сайте, но там уже не работает, хотя все одинаково, нет разницы в коде что на 1 что на 2 сайте

Comment: Это другое дело. Сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `'a',` из

```
$('.delete-input').on('click', 'a', function(){ ...
```

В Вашем html `'.delete-input'` и есть `а`.

*Update*

В свете новой информации, будем использовать *делегирование* для обработки кликов на элементах, которых не существует в момент регистрации обработчика:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-input', function(){ ...
```

Comment: спасибо большое, работает, но не могу понять почему.., как я и говорил что на первом сайте вариант `$('.delete-input').on('click', function(){` работает и в момент  регистрации обработчика не существует `.delete-input`, как это можно объяснить?

Comment: @harbor Не видя кода, это объяснить трудно. Возможно, регистрация обработчика вызывается все-таки не при загрузке страницы (в `$(document).ready(...)`), а после создания соответствующих элементов.

Comment: ну ладно, надо будет побольше изучить это, спасибо большое